# How do I find out a size of a stream in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, stream

I am trying to upload a zip file to Azure file shares. The zip file is being generated using the `archiver` library and I tried uploading it using piping. I am always getting the error `StorageError: The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.`. How do I find out the size of my archive? I tried 'collecting' the size of the zip like this:

```
const uploadStream = new stream.PassThrough();
    zip.pipe(uploadStream);
    zip.finalize();

zip.on("data", (chunk) => {
      this.zipSize += chunk.length;
    });

zip.on("finish", () => {
      console.log(this.zipSize);
      this._callFileService(uploadStream);
    });
```

```
async _callFileService(data: stream.PassThrough) {
    fileService.createShareIfNotExists(
      this.name,
      (error, result, response) => {
        if (!error) {

          fileService.createFileFromStream(
            this.name,
            "",
            "test.zip",
            data,
            this.zipSize,
            {},
            function (error, result, response) {
              if (error) {
                console.log(error);
              } else {
                console.log("Done upload");
                console.log(result, response);
              }
            },
          );
        } else {
          console.log("there was an error: ", error);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I also tried just fetching the size of the archive, and I tried using `stream.writableLength` but everything throws the same error. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try logging the data you send to this function ?
fileService.createFileFromStream

edit:
GJ solving this :)

- according to the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver
  zip.pointer() is the way to get the total size of the archive.
  no need to calculate "zipSize".
- zip.finalize() should be called last to prevent race conditions.
  at least after zip.on("finish").

Comment: 'The directory name. Use '' to refer to the base directory' this is the description for the directory param. I don't see the point of logging data in the function.. I  know that the data is correct because I tried storing it into a local .zip file and everything works fine.

Comment: i was curious about the value of zipSize. if you write the zip to a file, does it contain exactly the same amount of data ? Also, every similar error i see on google points to people trying to download, not uploading O_o. Interesting, but i am not sure i can help

Comment: Haha yeah I noticed that as well... When I export the zip to my local machine it is about 113KB in size, meanwhile `data.readableLength` was giving me 16430. I tried multiplying `data.readableLength` by ten and it seems to work but now when I download the file and try extract it I get an error "there seems to be some data at the end of the file"...

Comment: i think readableLength only gives you a buffer (in your case 16K) not the whole data. But, zipSize is 113K ?

Comment: I finally got it!! The only way to get the actual size of the archive is by using `zip.pointer()` which is.. a bit weird, but nonetheless.. Thanks so much for your help, feel free to edit your original answer and I'll accept it as a answer for any future fork who might struggle with this..